# group by column not having specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012

I am trying to obtain a list of Case_Id's where the case does not contain a specific RoleId using Microsoft Sql Server 2012.

For example, I would like to obtain a collection of Case_Id's that do not contain a RoleId of 4.

So from the data set below the query would exclude Case_Id's 49, 50, and 53.

```
    Id      RoleId  Person_Id   Case_Id
   --------------------------------------
    108     4       108         49
    109     1       109         49
    110     4       110         50
    111     1       111         50
    112     1       112         51
    113     2       113         52
    114     1       114         52
    115     7       115         53
    116     4       116         53
    117     3       117         53
```

So far I have tried the following

```
SELECT Case_Id
FROM [dbo].[caseRole] cr
WHERE cr.RoleId!=4
GROUP BY Case_Id ORDER BY Case_Id
```

Comment: don't you mean `cr.roleId <> 4`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `not exists` operator seems to fit your need exactly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Case_Id
FROM   [dbo].[caseRole] cr
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   [dbo].[caseRole] cr_inner
                   WHERE  cr_inner.Case_Id = cr.case_id 
                          AND cr_inner.RoleId = 4);
```

Comment: Awesome - I did attempt go down this route, but my brain wasn't accepting it... anyway, i have tested and works great. Many thanks for your time, will accept.

Answer (score 13):

Just add a `having` clause instead of `where`:

```
SELECT Case_Id
FROM [dbo].[caseRole] cr
GROUP BY Case_Id
HAVING SUM(case when cr.RoleId = 4 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
ORDER BY Case_Id;
```

Comment: Enjoying this variant - doing some sort of SUM did cross my mind, albeit briefly. I think Mureinik's answer is a little more self explanatory due to semantics. Will up-vote however.

Comment: @Phil . . . It would be interesting to know which has better performance on your data.  Sometimes Mureinik's would, sometimes this would.

Comment: This is probably the most beautiful solution

Comment: Tested this and Mureinik's solution. Both logics works. In my case, time elapsed on Gordon's method is of 89% of Mureinik's. So there's a 11% performance gain when using Gordon's. This number is stably reproduceable via either running the query or through sub tree cost of estimated plan. If performance is irrelevent to you then choose whichever you read more comfortable. For me the use of SUM is inspiring. Love it.

Comment: Performance of SUM >> Performace of Exists. At least in my scenario.