# SQL QUERY FOR selecting only products which does not contain one language

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select only those product which is *not having language-id "en-ZA"*.

In the below example I need to select only  product number "102".

| ProductNumber | Language-ID |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | En-Us |
| 100 | En-ZA |
| 100 | fr |
| 101 | En-Us |
| 101 | En-ZA |
| 101 | fr |
| 102 | En-Us |
| 102 | fr |

Comment: use `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [select rows that doesn´t have a value in one column, and have the same ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56657710/select-rows-that-doesn%c2%b4t-have-a-value-in-one-column-and-have-the-same-id). Or possibly better:  [group by column not having specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26060911/2778710)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by following query using `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT ProductNumber 
FROM TableName
GROUP BY ProductNumber
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN [Language-ID]='En-ZA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

The same query can be written using `NOT EXISTS` like the following.

```
SELECT ProductNumber
FROM TableName t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM TableName  t2
  WHERE [Language-ID] = 'En-ZA'
  AND t2.ProductNumber = t1.ProductNumber
)
GROUP BY ProductNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to identify Product numbers which may contain "en-ZA" by using:

```
select distinct ProductNumber
from TABLE
where Language-ID = 'en-ZA'
```

That gives you a list of all Product numbers which contain 'en-ZA'.

Using that list you can sort your main list like:

```
select ProductNumber, Language-ID
from TABLE
where ProductNumber not in (
  select distinct ProductNumber
  from TABLE
  where Language-ID = 'en-ZA'
)
```

Comment: not exists would be much faster

Comment: You don't need distinct either. That will just slow it down.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it using `left join` :

```
select t.ProductNumber
from (
  select distinct ProductNumber
  from mytable
  where Language_ID != 'En-ZA'
) t
left join (
  select *
  from mytable
  where Language_ID = 'en-ZA'
) as s on s.ProductNumber = t.ProductNumber
where s.ProductNumber is null
```

We determine the rows where  `Language_ID != 'En-ZA'` (100,101,102) and match it with the ones having `Language_ID = 'en-ZA'` (100,101), then select only the ones that are not matched using `where s.ProductNumber is null`

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y9Sj_LSe)

Answer (score 0):

use NOT EXISTS - it is simple and quite fast

```
select ProductNumber, Language-ID
from YourTable as YT1
where not exists (
  select 1
  from YourTable as YT2
  where YT2.Language-ID = 'en-ZA'
  and YT2.ProductNumber = YT1.ProductNumber
)
```